# Send an array with multiselect when selected only one option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I use [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) library to handle forms.

Field definition:

```js
<AsyncSelect 
    isMulti={true} 
    defaultOptions 
    cacheOptions 
    onChange={handleSelectChange} 
    name={formData.name}
    defaultValue={formData.defaultValue} 
    loadOptions={props.loadOptions}
/>
```

The library uses input fields to store selected values.
E.g.:

```html
<input name="artists_ids" type="hidden" value="3f9da869-a230-4fc6-8012-40a5f06d694e">
<input name="artists_ids" type="hidden" value="d9741ab8-784e-45bf-af92-0416e97730da">
```

To handle form data I use `FormData` object:

```js
    const handleSubmit = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        Router.post(props.routing, {body: new FormData(event.currentTarget)})
        //...
    })
```

API is restricted to get array of ids.

When the user selects more than one value everything works correctly:

```
{
    "artists_ids":["3f9da869-a230-4fc6-8012-40a5f06d694e","d9741ab8-784e-45bf-af92-0416e97730da"]
}
```

**The problem**

When the user tries to send only one selected value the `FormData` object converts data to string instead of array:

```
{
    "artists_ids": "3f9da869-a230-4fc6-8012-40a5f06d694e"
}
```

Solution which won't work:

- Modify `FormData` object which is send to server - I can't modify this object
- Add empty input to send array - request to API will fail
- Change API to get string or array as a parameter

**Question**

Do you know how to send array even the user selected only one field?

Comment: _"**My** API is restricted..."_ - So you could change it by adding a quick check if the input is just a simple string or an array?

Comment: @Andreas I can't change API (I already mentioned it).

Comment: @tex thank you for answer. About FormData I read some time ago that there is a problem with modifying this object because of security reasons also TypeScript returned information that `entries` method doesn't exists. In this case I will try to replace `FormData`. It requires additional effort (I need to manually grab data from many input/select components and merge it into one). If it's correct way to handle that it's ok for me.

Comment: Ufortunately it's not that easy - `fetch` method requires RequestInit interface which requires BodyInit interface which has specified types: `Blob | BufferSource | FormData | URLSearchParams | ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`. Now I need to manage how to create object from state which fulfit interface.

Comment: I don't know what your `Router.post` is doing. Is that from a well-known library? I also don't know what other fields are in your form (for instance, are you uploading a file here)? I do know it's not usually difficult to post the contents of a React form to an API via `fetch`.

Comment: The `Router` function is more like decorator for the native `fetch` function (I wrote it). In the `post` function I add default headers, method etc. Finally I call `fetch` with prepared data. Currently I don't have possibility to send files. Other fields are inputs with texts/numbers and select types.
All my forms works correctly except one with multi select when the user sends only one selected element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just wrap `artist_ids` in an array when it isn't already an array. Since you're somewhat constrained by your API and your generic `AddForm` function, the solution probably involves making that function slightly more flexible.

With that goal in mind, I'd add an optional `transform` function to your `IFormComponentProps` interface. Default the new `transform` prop to the identity function (`(x) => x`) when it's undefined. This ensures that `handleSubmit` will remain backwards-compatible with existing forms.

In `AddForm`, apply `props.transform` to the `RequestInit` argument to `Router.post` like this:

```js
export function AddForm(props: IFormComponentProps) {
    const { transform = (x) => x } = props
// ...
    const handleSubmit = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        Router.post(props.routing, transform({body: new FormData(event.currentTarget)}))
// ...
}
```

Since `BodyInit` can be a string, you should be able to supply a custom function that transforms your `new FormData` into an object (with `artists_ids` forced to be an array), then `JSON.stringify` that object, such that you end up calling `Router.post` with:

```js
{
  body: JSON.stringify(transformedFormDataObject),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}
```

That should do the trick (if the API can handle the content type) and should give you more flexibility, should you need it in the future.

If the API can't handle the content type, you'll need to convert your plain object back to a new `FormData` object after processing it to make sure `artists_ids` is an array (rather than `JSON.stringify`ing it).

Comment: I think it would be easier to explain everything if I share my repo.
Here is my form which I use to add/edit song (I have problem with this form):
https://gitlab.com/grzegorzmatuszak/music_crud_spa/blob/master/src/Song/Components/SongEditForm.tsx

I use only one component to add new elements in app:
https://gitlab.com/grzegorzmatuszak/music_crud_spa/blob/master/src/Shared/Components/Form/AddForm.tsx

I can't modify `handleSubmit` this way because it more abstract, I would need to modify whole app to handle it.

Comment: I thought to add to multiSelect hidden inputs and then in my `handleSubmit` check if specific field is an array and remove empty data from FormData, but then I need to modify FormData, also this solution doesn't looks nice.

Comment: You have a lot of generic infrastructure which is great when your needs follow the happy path, but which can limit your flexibility when you run into edge cases or need to add new functionality. I have added a suggestion in my answer, above, but for a more comprehensive solution, I would consider ditching your reliance on the forms' `onsubmit` events and `new FormData()` and trigger your form submissions with a regular button that calls the `handlesubmit` function, passing it the form's `formData` object (notice the small 'f'). This will greatly improve flexibility, and is more idiomatic.